# Changing class of the body with blazor

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, blazor

I want to dynamically change the class of the `<body>` element in blazor Wasm. Is this possible without using the javascript?

Comment: This sounds like a xy-problem. Please describe what you really want to solve.

Comment: The design team prepared classes for the body that will be used to change theme. It is important that class is added to <body> otherwise it will not work. So i want to offer a user an option to chanage this attribute with radio button, select etc..